# Java : export Device-Independent Bitmap stream contained in OLE column in Microsoft Access database

Tags: java, image, ms-access, ole, dib

I'm a Java developer, and I'm trying to export images contained in a Microsoft Access database.

The image object is stored in an OLE column that I've managed to read, but the content is a little bit strange due to the fact that the images were pasted into the table from clipboard. The result of my export is the binary stream below, and I don't have any idea about how to get an image from that.

[printscreen from notepad++ hex editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbOlu.png)

```
0x15, 0x1C, 0x1B, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x1A, 0x00, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x50, 0x68, 0x6F, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0x49, 0x42, 0x00, 0x95, 0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFC, 
0xEF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x50, 0x13, 0x03, 0x00, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x45, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x9B, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1C, 0x13, 0x03, 0x00, 0xC4, 
0x0E, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC4, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
```

Comment: Can you please replace that "text" dump with a hex-version of the same data? That would help in seeing what the values actually are... Most likely it is in fact a DIB (Device Independent Bitmap), and could probably be read by a BMP image reader (perhaps some data massaging is required).

Comment: Thank you @HaraldK for you comment. I've added a printscreen from my notepad++ hex editor so that you can see the hex content. most BMP image readers need the image content to stard with BMx.. you can see that it's not the case here

Comment: Even so, you should add the hex as text... I haven’t been able to look at it, as the screenshot is unreadable on my phone.

Comment: sorry @haraldK .. i thought the hex format hard to digest  ..